# Limiting saga_cmd memory usage

Tags: performance, saga, linux, command-line

I'm trying to perform a shrink operation on a large (13GB LZW compressed) raster in SAGA GIS on Linux:

```
saga_cmd grid_tools 28 -INPUT in.tif -RESULT out.tif -OPERATION 0 -RADIUS
 5
```

I have 64GB of RAM + 500GB of swap, but `saga_cmd` just consumes all of it before getting OOM (out of memory) killed.

Is there any option/technique to limit memory usage?

Splitting up the raster to process it in chunks is not an option, since the shrink operation will create gaps between the tiles.

Comment: About and option/technique to limit memory usage: maybe you are looking for cgroups: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cgroups, but you will just have the out of memory earlier.  About an alternative to SAGA: maybe a custom Python function can do it with a better memory management.